"Generate password and notify user immediately" using Salesforce flow
I am using a screen flow where the new users details are being captured. The requirement is to also show a checkbox named "Generate password and notify user immediately". Once an admin creates the record from the screen flow, the value of the "Generate password and notify user immediately" field will be pulled up from the checkbox.
I couldn't find any way I will be able to control the above field via flows.
Is there any way the checkbox can be controlled via the screen flow form.

I don't think you can access 'Generate password and notify user immediately' and you can trigger using flow. (https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZggUAF/default-false-for-field-generate-new-password-and-notify-user-immediately)
